# add row detail to tableHandle

Tags: birt

I am using BIRT DEAPI and i want to add a detail row to my table that alreadey exists

```
        TableHandle table = (TableHandle) findElementHandle(design
                .getBody(), 137);
        RowOperationParameters params= new RowOperationParameters(0, -1, 1);
        table.insertRow(params);
```

the problem is i can't unrestand what is RowOperationParameters parameters?
how i must create a RowOperationParameters that can be used to  insert a detail row in a table handle?

any help will be greatly appreciated
Mohammad G.H

Answer (score 0):

the response here :

http://www.birt-exchange.org/forum/designing-birt-reports/16624-how-add-detail-row-tablehandle.html#post53870